# Count consecutive non NA items

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr) 
temp<-as.data.frame(cbind(col_A<-c(1,2,NA,3,4,5,6),col_B<-c(NA,1,2,NA,1,NA,NA)))
names(temp)<-c("col_A","col_B")
col_A      col_B
 1         NA           
 2         1           
 NA        2
 3         NA
 4         3
 5         NA
 6         NA
```

I want to create a new dataframe which contains the count of non NA items for each column.
Like the following example:

```
count_A      count_B
 1           0           
 2           1           
 0           2
 1           0
 2           1
 3           0
 4           0
```

I am strugling in getting the count of items. 
My closest approximation is this:

```
count_days<-function(prev,new){
ifelse(!is.na(new),prev+1,0)
}

temp[,"col_A"] %>% 
mutate(count_a=accumulate(count_a,count_days))
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
   no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

Can anyone help me with this code or just give me another glance.

I know this piece of code just tries to count, not creating the new df, which I think is easier after I get the correct result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `rle` in a (somewhat nested) `lapply` approach. We first `list` if an element of the data `is.na`. Then, using `rle` we decode values and lengths. Those lengths which are `NA` we set to `0` by multiplication and `unlist` the thing.

```
res <- as.data.frame(lapply(lapply(temp, is.na), function(x) {
  r <- rle(x)
  s <- sapply(r$lengths, seq_len)
  s[r$values] <- lapply(s[r$values], `*`, 0)
  unlist(s)
}))
res
#   col_A col_B
# 1     1     0
# 2     2     1
# 3     0     2
# 4     1     0
# 5     2     1
# 6     3     0
# 7     4     0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to understand the code, and I can't understand how this line "s[r$values] <- lapply(s[r$values], `*`, 0)" gives the count.

Comment: The `s` is a list which we want to replace with the same class (list), but only where `r$values == TRUE` (i.e. where there are `NA` in `temp`). These values we want to set to (multiply by) `0`. `lapply(s[r$values], `*`, 0)` does exactly this by looping over `s` subsetted by `r$values == TRUE`. We just write `r$values`, since the ` == TRUE` is redundant. Does this make sense for you? You could actually examine the code inside the curly brackets line by line by doing `x <- lapply(temp, is.na)[[1]]`.

Comment: OK, now it makes sense, I was missdebugging. Thanks for the answer and the clariffication!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(temp)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) rowid(rleid(!is.na(x))) * !is.na(x))]
#    col_A col_B
#1:     1     0
#2:     2     1
#3:     0     2
#4:     1     0
#5:     2     1
#6:     3     0
#7:     4     0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
```

You can use `sequence` and `rle` from `data.table`
First set all non-NA as 1 and then `rle` count the sequence of same numbers

```
library(data.table)

temp %>% 
  replace(.,!is.na(.),1) %>% 
  mutate(col_A=case_when(!is.na(col_A)~sequence(rle(col_A)$lengths))) %>% 
  mutate(col_B=case_when(!is.na(col_B)~sequence(rle(col_B)$lengths))) %>% 
  replace(.,is.na(.),0)
```